# Get list of which file extensions are on a Mac recursively

Tags: linux, macos, find

I would like a list of which file extensions are on a Mac.  I would like to search all files recursively.

Expected output:

```
  tar.gz
  txt
  pdf
  png
  jpg
```

I tried the following:

```
  find . | grep '\.'| tail -c 4  
  ls -lR | grep '\.'| tail -c 4
```

The output is just "txt", but there are many more extensions such as pdf, png, jpg, etc.
How can I get the rest of the expected output?

Sample input files

```
$ tree
.
├── foobar.tar.gz
├── 02_quest_cbc.pdf
├── 16_iron_panel.pdf
├── 16_lots.pdf
├── 18_cbc.pdf
├── 20_kaiser.txt
├── com
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   ├── project.txt
│   └── readme.txt
└── txt

1 directory, 11 files
```

Comment: Do you have `file` command utility ?

Comment: And what is the output of `file -i file.foo` ?

Comment: Don't confuse file extension with file type.   Sometimes the extension is used to determine file type, but more commonly posix style systems will use a heuristic based on file content, generally the fist bytes of the file.  `file` would be a good utility to determine which type each file is.

Comment: I just clarified the question that I am more interested in extensions than file types.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, assuming files don't have dots in filenames, except for extensions:

```
$ tree
.
├── foobar.tar.gz
├── 02_quest_cbc.pdf
├── 16_iron_panel.pdf
├── 16_lots.pdf
├── 18_cbc.pdf
├── 20_kaiser.txt
├── com
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   ├── project.txt
│   └── readme.txt
└── txt

1 directory, 11 files
```

```
find . -type f | awk -F. '
    {
        if      (NF==2) {sub(/\.\//, ""); arr[$0]}
        else if (NF==3) {arr[$NF]}
        else if (NF>3)  {arr[$(NF-1)"."$NF]}
    }
    END{for (i in arr) print i}'
```

###### Output

```
tar.gz
pdf
png
sh
txt
```

---

##### A more robust approach is to install GNU `file` with `homebrew`, then:

```
$ find . -exec file -i {} \; | perl -nE 'say $1 if m|\s+\w+/(\w+);|' | sort -u
```

Comment: When I run this command the Mac pauses for about 5 seconds, and then returns nothing.

Comment: Try the second one

Comment: 20_kaiser.txt
16_iron_panel.pdf
02_quest_cbc.pdf
16_lots.pdf
18_cbc.pdf
com/readme.txt
com/project.txt
com/2.png
com/1.png
txt

Comment: I guess you'd want to ensure each is only printed once.

Comment: @GillesQuénot : you can skip all the incrementing `arr[  ]++` since the print out only cares about existence of hash key not its frequency.

Comment: Post edited accordingly , thanks

Answer (score 0):

find . -type f | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq

Comment: always de-dupe before sorting : you can consolidate the last 3 items to ::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::  `awk -F'.' '!_[ $!NF = $NF ]++' | sort`